# XRPL: Request account info for multiple accounts

Tags: xrp

Is there a way to request account info for multiple XRPL accounts at the same time with the new WebSocket API's?

When I check on the website: https://xrpl.org/account_info.html I only see an explanation for getting info on 1 account. But let's say I have an interface with 30 XRP accounts, can I request the XRPL info on all 30 of them with a single request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. You have to request the info for each account in a separate request.